# Fix damage done by Add-AppxPackage

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday, all of a sudden, my Calculator app would not work anymore in Windows 10. It would open then immediately close.

I searched online for a solution, and I came accross one that re-registered the modern apps in Windows 10, so I gave it a shot. This was the powershell command that I ran:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

It looks like this command works in Windows 10 build 10240, but it breaks the Windows Store apps in build 10586. I have build 10586, so the command broke all my Windows Store apps.

My question is: how can I fix the damage done by that command, without reinstalling Windows? I have no system restore points to go back to, and I also don't want to reinstall Windows or do an in-place upgrade.

I tried `sfc /scannow`, and also `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. They did not fix the problem.

Comment: Your Windows Store applications were broken before you ran that command by the way, hence the reason, Calculator was crashing.

Comment: @Ramhound maybe, but only Calculator was broken. Now they are all broken.

Comment: [You will need to use the Reset option built into Windows 10 to solve this problem](http://superuser.com/questions/1015056/windows-store-apps-greyed-out-windows-10)